# how can post multiple different parameters with postman?

Tags: postman

I  want to use postman to sent the POST request to the server, the required parameters is like this:

```
public BasicResponse teacherReUpload(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        @RequestParam String token,
        @RequestParam("correctActivities") List<ActivityDetails> correctActivities,
        @RequestParam List<ActivityDetails> failureActivities)
```

I'd like to send one string parameter and two json paramaters through Postman. How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: You can create a POJO that has these two lists as two members(poperties). Now you can send the string in the url and post the POJO data

Comment: can I send two jason prameters through postman?

Comment: If you have a class that has these two lists as members then you can post something like this `{
    "correctActivities" : [],
    "failureActivities" : []
}`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've solved this problem by using Map<ArrayList<ActivityDetails>>